# How to remove the whitespace for this section in YAAC resume?

Tags: spacing, white-space, awesome-cv

I am building up my CV in `Latex` using this `cv format` [YAAC: Another Awesome CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-source-cv/wrdjtkkytqcw). But the `projects section in metadata class` is creating `whitespace` and that makes my cv very weird. I have tried `\titlespacing` and other issues but failed. Is there anyone who can solve this or suggest how to do it? Thanks in Advance.
[image: The Problems in my CV]

```
% Define the 'projects' environment
\newenvironment{projects}{%
  \begin{longtable}{l}
}{% 
  \end{longtable}
}

% Define the 'project' entry in the 'projects' environment
% Usage:
% \project
%   {<Project name>}{<dates>}
%   {<link1> <link2>}
%   {<Project description>}
%   {<techno1>,<techno2>}
\newcommand\project[5]{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth) - 1.5em}
    \textbf{\textsc{#1}} \hfill \textsc{#2}\smallskip\\
    #3\\
    #4\smallskip\\
    \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#5}{\cvtag{\n}}}\\
  \end{minipage}
  \\
}

\sectionTitle{Thesis \& Projects}{\faLaptop}

\begin{projects}
    \project
    {Risk Assessment and Drug Design Using R: Heart Diseases | Undergraduate Thesis}{July 2018 - Dec 2018}
    {Designed a common pathway drug (computer-aided) for all types of heart diseases
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Integrated R with different biological database to extract bio data 
        \item Data mining application KKD is applied to obtain the goal
\end{itemize}       
    }
    {\textit{Bitbucket Repo}: \href{https://bitbucket.org/mustanjid/risk-assessment-and-drug-design-using-r-heart-diseases}{https://bitbucket.org/mustanjid/risk-assessment-and-drug-design-using-r-heart-diseases}}
    {Recognized as \textbf{best dissertation} in the course of the semester.}

    \project
    {Travo - A Travel Blog | Academic Project}{Jan 2018 - Apr 2018} 
    {Implemented a web platform where travellers can stroe \& share their travel stories.}
    {\github{Al-mustanjid/Travellers_Project} \website{https://travo.herokuapp.com/places}{Travo}}
    {node.js, express.js, mongodb}
    \project
    {Giftz - An E-commerce site | Academic Project}{Sep 2017 - Dec 2017} 
    {An E-commerce website where customer can buy and gift items.}
    {\github{Al-mustanjid/Giftz}}
    {ASP.NET, Sql, Web Technologies}
\end{projects}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a minimal working example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I have updated the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why only that section has different spacing,
in case you are looking for quick fix just use

```tex
% Define the 'projects' environment
\newenvironment{projects}{%
  \begin{longtable}{l}
}{%
  \end{longtable}
  \vspace{-1em}  %here I've taken away the space
}
```

at line 407 in `yaac-another-awesome-cv.cls`

**output**
[image]